# AppFabric installed & Configured : Unable to Install SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, administration, farm-admin

I had installed app-fabric and configured it.But I am unable to install SharePoint 2013 and encountering below error.Can anyone help what might be the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First Uninstall exisiting installation of AppFabric

Delete “PSModulePath” from system environment variables entry.

Restart server  try below steps

Step 1: regedit-->search  "AppFabric" and delete all entries in regedit

Step 2:restart

Step 3: Open powershell as admin

Step 4: run the below command

$SharePoint2013Path = "D:\Appl\SP"

Start-Process "$SharePoint2013Path\PrerequisiteInstaller.exe" /KB2671763:$SharePoint2013Path\PrerequisiteInstallerFiles\AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe

Start-Process "$SharePoint2013Path\PrerequisiteInstaller.exe" /AppFabric:$SharePoint2013Path\PrerequisiteInstallerFiles\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe

Step  5: Restart

Answer (score 0):

It looks the App fabric still is not configured properly, you should uninstall it from the control panel, then install it again.

- In case you have internet connection on your machine try to run The prerequisites again.
- In case you didn't have an intent connection, try to install App fabric in offline mode.

  - by running this command in CMD `.\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe /i /gac`
  - Wait until AppFabric installation finish.
  - Click on ‘AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe’ to install the AppFabric patch.
  - Reboot the server > Run SharePoint Installation again where the message error should not be listed again.

I mentioned the detail steps at [Windows Server AppFabric is not correctly configured.You Should uninstall Windows Server AppFabric and reinstall it using The SharePoint Products Preparation Tool.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/06/14/windows-server-appfabric-is-not-correctly-configured-as-sharepoint-2013-prerequisites/)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below links they might be helpful:

1. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2013/02/21/sharepoint-2013-prerequisites-fails-with-msi-installer-error-code-1603-while-installing-appfabric-1-1/
2. https://helmymo7amed.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/sharepoint-2013-appfabric-installation-error/

Below solutions are included in the above links but if in case links go down then below solutions might be helpful.

**Solution 1**

Uninstall the installed AppFabric. Open CMD and run the following command:

```
c:\SP2013>prerequisiteinstaller.exe /AppFabric:prerequisiteinstallerfiles\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe
/KB2671763:prerequisiteinstallerfiles\AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe
```

System will restart. Once it is restarted, open again sharepoint installation and it will restarted successfully.

**Solution 2**

Append the following path to PSModulePath entry in the environment variables – %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

- Go to My Computer, right-click Properties.
- On the System’ page, click Advanced System Settings on the left-side pane.
- If you receive a UAC prompt, click on Yes to launch the System Properties dialog box.
- From the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.
- Within the System    Variables section in the lower half, select
  PSModulePath and click on    Edit (or double-click PSModulePath‘)
- Append the following path to PSModulePath entry in the environment variables

  %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
- Ensure that the PSModulePath entry looks like this:

  C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\PowershellModules

**Solution 3**

- There are chances that other applications might be referencing the
  same variable and may fail if it is deleted. This is what we can do
  if solution 1 does not help.
- Remove the PSModulePath entry from the ‘Environment Variables’ and
  re-run the installer. Once it completes successfully, ensure that the
  PSModulePath entry looks the same as mentioned in solution 2.

**Solution 4**

Follow these steps for installing AppFabric for Windows Server correctly:

- Uninstall the Appfabric for Windows Server from Control Panel ->
  Programs and Features page.
- Download the individual requirements to a network location or a local
  folder
- Install prerequisites for SharePoint 2013 manually
- From the Start menu, open the Command Prompt window using the Run as
  administrator option.

  --> Navigate to the root of the SharePoint 2013 installation media or folder location.

  --> Type the prerequisite program switch and corresponding argument for the program that you want to install, and then press ENTER. 
  For example:

  If we have to install AppFabric for Windows Server from a local source, we can run the following command:

  PrerequisiteInstaller.exe /AppFabric:

  This will kick off the prerequisite installer wizard which will then use the installation file stored locally on the machine as specified in the command-line to install Windows Server AppFabric. We can also install more than one prerequisite by using different switches with the PrerequisiteInstaller.exe command to install multiple components and specifying the installation path in the command line window. For example:

  PrerequisiteInstaller.exe /AppFabric: /IDFX11:

  This command will install Appfabric and Windows Identity Foundation

  For a complete list of prerequisite installer operations and command-line options, see [Prerequisite installer operations and command-line options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#section7)
- The SharePoint 2013 prerequisite installer
  (prerequisiteinstaller.exe) installs the following software, if it
  has not already been installed on the server, in this order (provided
  you have downloaded the prerequisites locally):

  PrerequisiteInstaller.exe
  /SQLNCli:file – Install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client from file 
  /PowerShell:file – Install Windows Management Framework 3.0 from file 
  /NETFX:file – Install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 from file 
  /IDFX:file – Install Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405) from file 
  /Sync:file – Install Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64) from file 
  /AppFabric: 
  /IDFX11:"\Microsoft Identity Extensions.msi" 
  /MSIPCClient:"\msipc.msi" 
  /WCFDataServices:"\WcfDataServices.exe" 
  /KB2671763:"\AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe

where "file" signifies the file location from where you want to install. If you do not specify the  option, the installer downloads the file from the Internet and installs it.

The prerequisite installer creates log files at `%TEMP%\prerequisiteinstaller.<date>.<time>.log`. You can check these log files for specific details about all changes the installer makes to the server.

Comment: The links might answer the question, but they might not be helpful if they go down in future. So it is better to include necessary portion of the link in the answer.

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri, you are right links might go down and thus I included their content.